# ¿Qué significa en este código key=getint y que requiero para usarlo?(esta en python)

Tags: python

Deseo hacer un gráfico 3D, y encontre este código para hacerlo, pero no tengo claro lo que me pide. Sé que necesito un grd pero no se que hace la función getint ni con qué se usa. Adjunto el código.

```
    import glob
    def getint(name):
        _, num = name.split('P_')
        num, _ = num.split('.')
        return int(num)

    filenames = glob.glob("/opt/uio/deep_python/data/Grace/grd_files_to_interp/GypsumP_*.grd")

    filenames = sorted(filenames, key=getint)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está llamando a la función [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (para ordenar), y dice que la clave que se va a tener en cuenta para ordenar va a ser lo que devuelva la operación de ejecutar `getint` con cada elemento de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```py
def getint(name):
    _, num = name.split('P_')
    num, _ = num.split('.')
    return int(num)

lista = [ 'P_3.abc', 'P_2.abc', 'P_32.abc', 'P_11.abc', 'P_1.abc' ]
ordenada = sorted(lista, key=getint)

print(ordenada) # Muestra: ['P_1.abc', 'P_2.abc', 'P_3.abc', 'P_11.abc', 'P_32.abc']
```

Dentro de la función `getint` está dividiendo las cadenas de texto que pases, entre `P_` y `.`, así se queda con el número de cada cadena, y lo convierte en un número (`int(num)`).

Lo que necesitas es asegurar que todos los elementos de esa lista `filenames` tienen un formato en el que existe un solo `P_` y luego tiene `.`, y que entre ese `P_` y ese `.` hay números.

Comment: crees que sea solo el nombre del archivo? porque involucra la libreria glob para llamar a los archivos... es como si buscara P_1 dentro del .grd, y no estoy clara de como lo esta buscando porque un archivo grd no abre con cualquier programa. gracias por responder!

Comment: Bueno, lo que hace la función `glob` es encontrar todos los archivos de la carpeta: `/opt/uio/deep_python/data/Grace/grd_files_to_interp/`, cuyo nombre sea `GypsumP_*.grd`, donde el `*` quiere decir "cualquier carácter", o sea, encontrará todos los archivos que empiecen por "GypsumP_" y terminen por ".grd". No abre nada, solo los encuentra y crea una lista con esos nombres de archivo (con el _path_ completo "/opt/uio/.../GypsumP_*.grd")

Comment: muchas graciass! ahora si entendi todo!!